# javascript, замыкания, проблемы синтаксиса

Tags: javascript, синтаксис, замыкания

Есть код на JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

var site = (function ()
{
    var loader_html = '<img src="/img/loader.gif" width="100" height="100" />';
    var loader_image_width = 100;
    var loader_image_height = 100;

    return
    {
        window_subroutines : {
            get_scrollTop : function () { return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || (document.body && document.body.scrollTop); },
            get_scrollLeft : function () { return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) || (document.body && document.body.scrollLeft); },
            get_clientWidth : function () { return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) || (document.body && document.body.clientWidth); },
            get_clientHeight : function () { return (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) || (document.body && document.body.clientHeight); }
        },

        loader : {
            show : function () {
                var loader_elem = document.getElementById ("loader_container");
                var left_coord = Math.round(site.window_subroutines.get_scrollLeft() + ( site.window_subroutines.get_clientWidth() / 2 ) - ( loader_image_width / 2 )) + "px";
                var top_coord = Math.round(site.window_subroutines.get_scrollTop() + ( site.window_subroutines.get_clientHeight() / 2 ) - ( loader_image_height / 2 )) + "px";

                loader_elem.innerHTML = loader_html;
                loader_elem.style.top = top_coord;
                loader_elem.style.left = left_coord;

                loader_elem.style.display = "block";
            },

            hide : function () { setTimeout("document.getElementById('loader_container').style.display = 'none';", 750); }
        }
    };

})();
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке его выполнить браузер выводит ошибку:

> SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
>
> `get_scrollTop : function () { return (document.documentElement && document.docum...`

Посмотреть живьём это можно на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zdnLdqn8/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Надо изменить

```
return
{
```

на

```
return {
```

JavaScript добавляет `;` в конец строка автоматическим образом, так что код распарсится так:

```
return;
{ // блок кода
  window_subroutines: // метка
  { // блок кода
    get_scrollTop : // метка
    function () { /* ... */ } // SyntaxError: декларация функции без имени
```

(Смотрите в спецификации о [инструкциях с метками](http://es5.javascript.ru/x12.html#x12.12) и [автоматической подстановке точки с запятой](http://es5.javascript.ru/x7.html#x7.9))

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное.